# Create a shared page for update a record (based on the table of the record) as deleted after filling a note text

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 22.1 and I have some tables like `TBLCASE`, `TBLCASE_CLASSES`, .... . which all have the columns `ISDELETED`, `DELETE_TIME`, `DELETE_USER` and `DELETE_NOTE`. What I want is:

When the user is in any report page and click on delete a dialog page show up, in this dialoge I want to show a different text for each table and a Note text field (:P32_NOTE) the user must enter before confirming.

Besides the id item (:P32_ID) I added an item to hold the table name (:P32_TABLE) and an item to hold the text (:P32_DISPLAY). all of them came from the link so there is no problem.

And I used if else based on :P32_TABLE item.

```
BEGIN
    IF :P32_TABLE = 'TBLCASE' THEN
        UPDATE TBLCASE SET ISDELETED = 1, DELETE_TIME = LOCALTIMESTAMP, DELETE_USER = :APP_USER, DELETE_NOTE = :P32_NOTE:
        WHERE ID = :P32_ID;
    ELSIF :P32_TABLE = 'TBLCASECALSS' THEN
        UPDATE TBLCASECLASS SET ISDELETED = 1, DELETE_TIME = LOCALTIMESTAMP, DELETE_USER = :APP_USER, DELETE_NOTE = :P32_NOTE:
        WHERE ID = :P32_ID;
    ELSIF :P32_TABLE = 'TBLCASEDOCUMENT' THEN
        UPDATE TBLCASEDOCUMENT SET ISDELETED = 1, DELETE_TIME = LOCALTIMESTAMP, DELETE_USER = :APP_USER, DELETE_NOTE = :P32_NOTE:
        WHERE ID = :P32_ID;
    ELSIF :P32_TABLE = 'TBLCASEEND' THEN
        UPDATE TBLCASEEND SET ISDELETED = 1, DELETE_TIME = LOCALTIMESTAMP, DELETE_USER = :APP_USER, DELETE_NOTE = :P32_NOTE:
        WHERE ID = :P32_ID;
    END IF;
END;
```

But only if `:P32_TABLE = TBLCASE` works. What is the problem

Comment: What does 'only TBLCASE works' ***mean***? Do you get error messages? If so, include them here. If not, what does happen?  *(Also, note that you have a typo; `:P32_TABLE = 'TBLCASECALSS'`)*

Comment: No error and nothing happen. The record did not update.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Then it's likely that the table names do not match the strings in your IF statements. *(Such as the strings missing `_` characters.)*

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is because you misspelled the names of the tables In the comparisons. It will be better if you used a dynamic method like `execute immediate`. I will show you how:

First, create a database `PROCEDURE` to execute the update command.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE DELETE_OPERATION
  ( 
    P_ID      number , 
    P_TABLE  VARCHAR2, 
    P_USER    VARCHAR2 , 
    P_NOTES VARCHAR2 )
AS
v_cmd VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
    v_cmd := 'UPDATE ' || P_TABLE || ' SET ISDELETED = 1, DELETE_TIME = LOCALTIMESTAMP, DELETE_USER = :1, DELETE_NOTE = :2;'
    || ' WHERE ID = ' TO_CHAR(P_ID);

    execute immediate v_cmd USING P_USER, P_NOTES ;
END;
```

Then replace this code.

```
BEGIN
    IF :P32_TABLE = 'TBLCASE' THEN
        UPDATE TBLCASE SET ISDELETED = 1, DELETE_TIME = LOCALTIMESTAMP, DELETE_USER = :APP_USER, DELETE_NOTE = :P32_NOTE:
        WHERE ID = :P32_ID;
    ELSIF :P32_TABLE = 'TBLCASECALSS' THEN
        UPDATE TBLCASECLASS SET ISDELETED = 1, DELETE_TIME = LOCALTIMESTAMP, DELETE_USER = :APP_USER, DELETE_NOTE = :P32_NOTE:
        WHERE ID = :P32_ID;
    ELSIF :P32_TABLE = 'TBLCASEDOCUMENT' THEN
        UPDATE TBLCASEDOCUMENT SET ISDELETED = 1, DELETE_TIME = LOCALTIMESTAMP, DELETE_USER = :APP_USER, DELETE_NOTE = :P32_NOTE:
        WHERE ID = :P32_ID;
    ELSIF :P32_TABLE = 'TBLCASEEND' THEN
        UPDATE TBLCASEEND SET ISDELETED = 1, DELETE_TIME = LOCALTIMESTAMP, DELETE_USER = :APP_USER, DELETE_NOTE = :P32_NOTE:
        WHERE ID = :P32_ID;
    END IF;
END;
```

With this:

```
BEGIN
    DELETE_OPERATION(:P32_ID, :P32_TABLE, :APP_USER, :P32_NOTE);
END;
```

Comment: This is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: I updated the answer to use `USING P_USER, P_NOTES`  to prevent sql injection attacks.